# New Warning in gcc 7.4.0 with respect to gcc 5.4.9

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

Some days ago I updated my UBUNTU distribution from 16.04.12 to 18.04.01.

This update caused the transition from gcc-5.4.0 to gcc-7-4-0.

In this system I developed an application in c that previously, compiled with the -Wall option,
did not generate warnings.

Now I obtain the following warning:

```
src/load_input_file.c: In function ‘load_input_file’:
src/load_input_file.c:60:23: warning: ‘%s’ directive writing up to 499 bytes into a region of size 196 [-Wformat-overflow=]                                                                                           o 
sprintf(str,"cp %s %s",fileName,inputData.outDir);
                   ^~           ~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:862:0,
             from hdr/load_input_file.h:3,
             from src/load_input_file.c:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:33:10: note: ‘__builtin___sprintf_chk’ output 5 or more bytes (assuming 504) into a destination of size 200                                                                                             
  return __builtin___sprintf_chk (__s, __USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL - 1,
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      __bos (__s), __fmt, __va_arg_pack ());
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Could you help me to understand what is this warning and how to solve it?
Thank you

To solve the issue, following the suggestion of KamilCuk I trnsformed the code in the following way

```
sprintf(str,"cp %s %s",fileName,inputData.outDir);
```

to

```
sprintf(str,"cp ");
snprintf(str+strlen(str),strlen(fileName),"%s ",fileName);
snprintf(str+strlen(str),strlen(inputData.outDir),"%s",inputData.outDir);
```

Thank you

Comment: Please post an [MCVE] that would allow others to reproduce the warning. The warnings is kind of clear - you try to write with` snprintf` 499 bytes into `str` - a region that has the size of 196.

Comment: You are right. I edit the original post to put the solution. Than You

Comment: Your usage of `snprintf` is very invalid. Most probably your program invokes undefined behavior by overflowing allowed memory allocated for `str`. Please create and post a fully compilable, shortest as possible source code that let's others reproduce the problem you are having. Ex. I have gcc installed on my PC. What do I need to do to reproduce the warning?

Comment: I found the bug. str was declared of length 200 but inputData.outDir was declared of length 1024. Changing the length of str in 2048 no warnings during the compilation. LPs well define the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read [HERE](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/changes.html) GCC 7.1 introduced `Wformat-overflow` option.
This is why now is giving you that warning.

Most probably

```
sprintf(str,"cp %s %s",fileName,inputData.outDir);
```

can overflow because

```
sizeof(fileName)+sizeof(inputData.outDir) > sizeof(str)
```